# XML with XSLT is not rendered properly in IE11

Tags: xml, xslt, internet-explorer-11

I have following XML & XSLT, when I open with the XML with IE11, it is not rendered properly.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="StyleSheet.xsl" ?> 
<FIXML>
    <Header>
        <RequestID>ReqID8942</RequestID>
    </Header>
    <Body>
     <Data>
      <LimitDetails>
        <LimitRefNo>L1</LimitRefNo>
        <LimitClassification>ROOT</LimitClassification>
        <ParentLimitRefNo></ParentLimitRefNo>
        <ApprovedLimit>100.0</ApprovedLimit>
      </LimitDetails>
      <LimitDetails>
        <LimitRefNo>L2</LimitRefNo>
        <LimitClassification>ClASSIFICATION1</LimitClassification>
        <ParentLimitRefNo>L1</ParentLimitRefNo>
        <ApprovedLimit>200.0</ApprovedLimit>
      </LimitDetails>
      <LimitDetails>
        <LimitRefNo>L3</LimitRefNo>
        <LimitClassification>CLASSIFICATION2</LimitClassification>
        <ParentLimitRefNo>L2</ParentLimitRefNo>
        <ApprovedLimit>300.0</ApprovedLimit>
      </LimitDetails>
      <LimitDetails>
        <LimitRefNo>L4</LimitRefNo>
        <LimitClassification>CLASSIFICATION3</LimitClassification>
        <ParentLimitRefNo>L3</ParentLimitRefNo>
        <ApprovedLimit>400.0</ApprovedLimit>
      </LimitDetails>
      </Data>
   </Body>
</FIXML>
```

AND XSL is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0"  />
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Data">
    <xsl:copy>
        <LimitDetails>
            <Limit>
                <xsl:apply-templates select=".//LimitDetails[./ParentLimitRefNo='']" />
            </Limit>
        </LimitDetails>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="LimitDetails">
    <xsl:variable name="LimitRefNo" select="./LimitRefNo" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    <xsl:if test="../LimitDetails[./ParentLimitRefNo = $LimitRefNo]">
    <SubLimit>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../LimitDetails[./ParentLimitRefNo = $LimitRefNo]" />
    </SubLimit>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

when I open the XML with IE11 , only text nodes are displayed, it is not shown as XML format, please let me know what is wrong with this.

Comment: A browser is designed to display HTML, not the XML result of an XSL transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Change `<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0"  />` to
`<xsl:output method="html" version="1.0"  />` and check

Comment: Thanks for the reply, tried this but it did not work